# Loop an array with an "click" function

Tags: jquery, function, loops, click

I'm trying to have it so that whenever the button is clicked it will then change to the next background image.

```js
var images = [
  "http://helenspeyer.co.uk/wp-content/gallery/the-end-of-the-f-ing-world/The-end-of-the-f...ing-world-2-Large.jpg",
  "http://helenspeyer.co.uk/wp-content/gallery/the-end-of-the-f-ing-world/The-end-of-the-f...ing-world-6-Large.jpg",
  "http://helenspeyer.co.uk/wp-content/gallery/the-end-of-the-f-ing-world/The-end-of-the-f...ing-world-1-Large.jpg"
]

for (var i = 0; i < images.length; i++) {
  $("#changeBg").click(function() {
    $("body").css("background-image", "images.length[i]");
  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a few issues in your code. Firstly you need to attach a *single* event handler and progress through the elements of array on each successive click event. Attaching the event handlers in a loop will just create conflicts, as you're instantly trying to do the same action multiple times.

Within the single event handler you can use a variable to keep track of your current position in the array and increment it on each click. A `data` attribute is ideal for this.

Secondly, you need to actually use the value within the array element, not wrap that reference in quotes. You also need to access the array by index, not the `length` property specifically.

Lastly you need to wrap the URL of the image in the CSS attribute in `url("...")`.

```js
var images = [
  "https://helenspeyer.co.uk/wp-content/gallery/the-end-of-the-f-ing-world/The-end-of-the-f...ing-world-2-Large.jpg",
  "https://helenspeyer.co.uk/wp-content/gallery/the-end-of-the-f-ing-world/The-end-of-the-f...ing-world-6-Large.jpg",
  "https://helenspeyer.co.uk/wp-content/gallery/the-end-of-the-f-ing-world/The-end-of-the-f...ing-world-1-Large.jpg"
]

$("#changeBg").click(function() {
  var counter = $(this).data('counter') || 0;
  $("body").css("background-image", 'url("' + images[counter % images.length] + '")');
  $(this).data('counter', ++counter);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id="changeBg">Change background</button>
```

Comment: Thank you Rory, still getting a better working of jquery

Comment: Actually I was trying `var i = 0;

$("#changeBg").click(function() {
  $("body").css("background-image", \`url("${images[i]}")\`);
  i += (i < images.length ? 1 : -(images.length));
})` and it didn't work, the image didn't change on click. Any clue what is wrong with that code?

Comment: Why is that an issue? And even if it is, why doesn't it execute the $.css part even once? Is there any logical mistake in `i += (i < images.length ? 1 : -(images.length));`? Could maybe be simplified to `i += (i < images.length ? 1 : -i);`

Comment: The issue there is because you allow `i` to be incremented up to `3`, for which there is no matching index in the array.

Comment: How can it get incremented to 3 at any time?

Comment: Check the console to see the output: https://jsfiddle.net/4ur7k2tm/5/. The fix is to take one off the extents of the array when checking and resetting: `i += (i < (images.length - 1) ? 1 : -(images.length - 1));` https://jsfiddle.net/4ur7k2tm/4/. Note that this is a ***really*** ugly and hacky solution which should never be used. Using a modulo operator without the global variable is the best way to do this, by far

Comment: Potential `% 0` is not a problem? E.g. in a scenario where you get that list of images async and someone clicks the button before the async data is available.

Comment: That would be an issue, but there are a lot of things you should be doing to ensure validity of the retrieved data before that point.

Comment: True. It might be just me but whenever I need something divided I immediately start asking myself "could it be zero at any point".

Answer (score 1):

Rory explained it perfectly and also mentioned what's wrong with your code. The main issue was that you were unable to keep the trace of how many times the button was clicked.

And Rory gave a pretty good solution using the *data* attribute.

However, there's one more (or may be many more) way to solve the problem. Using **Closures**.

```
var images = [
  "http://helenspeyer.co.uk/wp-content/gallery/the-end-of-the-f-ing-world/The-end-of-the-f...ing-world-2-Large.jpg",
  "http://helenspeyer.co.uk/wp-content/gallery/the-end-of-the-f-ing-world/The-end-of-the-f...ing-world-6-Large.jpg",
  "http://helenspeyer.co.uk/wp-content/gallery/the-end-of-the-f-ing-world/The-end-of-the-f...ing-world-1-Large.jpg"
];

(function(){
  var count = 0;
  $("#changeBg").click(function(){
    var imgNo = count % images.length;
    document.body.style.backgroundImage = "url( " + images[imgNo] + ")";
    count++;
  });
})();
```

In this case, the event handler function has closure over the count variable. For details on closure, I would suggest you to go through this page -> https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Closures